# Failed to attach to debugger

Tags: debugging

I am working on a project in visual studio, and unable to attach w3wp process in visual studio, it's showing me that the attach was right, so the red circle appears solid, but when I refresh the page, it doesn't stop to debug.

I tried attaching the process using debug menu, then attach to process, I also tried using CKS dev tools.

Any idea where to start debugging this issue?

Comment: Is your project built and deployed in Debug mode?

Comment: how do I check that?

Comment: In visual studio, below the top menu, kind of in the center of the screen is a dropdown stating Debug och Release.

Comment: On the properties for the project, the configuration says: Debug (Active). Is that it?

Comment: ah yea, it says debug.